# Random Array of username prefixes

Tags: php, arrays, random, prefixes

Modifying my chat website and I want to add a random assortment of prefixes when people join.
right not the php code is:
 `define("ANONYMOUS_PREFIX", "user");`
which outputs as: user9367 joined.

Here's what I want done, but I have no hope with php.

```
define("ANONYMOUS_PREFIX", "$array"); 
$array = array(Mrs., Mr., Ms., Prof., Dr., Gen., Rep., Sen., St.);
```

Not to mention making it randomize.

Comment: well, it's a constant you cannot expect it to be dynamic? Btw. try array_rand

Comment: You can `define` only `scalar` values.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_rand()`

```
$array = array('Mrs.', 'Mr.', 'Ms.', 'Prof.', 'Dr.', 'Gen.', 'Rep.', 'Sen.', 'St');
$prefix = $array[array_rand($array)];
define ("ANONYMOUS_PREFIX", $prefix);
var_dump(ANONYMOUS_PREFIX);
```

**Note** that you can only assign scalar values to constants.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you're more of a user of your chat software than a programmer I'll suggest you simply replace the define with this one line:

```
define("ANONYMOUS_PREFIX", array_rand(array_flip(array("Dr", "Mr", "Ms", "Prof"))));
```

If you want to add more prefixes always write them in brackets and add a comma before.

Answer (score 0):

A constant cannot store an array you need to use a regular variable. For randomizing use the function `shuffle()`:

```
$array = array(Mrs., Mr., Ms., Prof., Dr., Gen., Rep., Sen., St.);
shuffle($array);

// you can assign the first element to the constant if you need to:
define('PREFIX', $array[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mt_rand()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php) to find a random index in your prefixes array and then define that prefix.
I figure it is faster to find one random number than to randomly shuffle an array, especially considering the fact said this array might become bigger over time.

```
<?php
$prefixes = array(Mrs., Mr., Ms., Prof., Dr., Gen., Rep., Sen., St.);
mt_srand(microtime());
$randval = mt_rand(0,count($prefixes));
$prefix = $prefixes[$randval];
define("ANONYMOUS_PREFIX", $prefix);
```